# gamm4 output size is too large (~5GB). How to decrease?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, lme4, mixed-models

I am running a Generalized Additive Mixed Model with the R package, gamm4. Each model output includes a mer object and a gam object. I need to compare 26 model structures based on a combination of variables and then conduct model averaging on the best models based on AIC.

The problem is, each .rds file with model output is approximately 5GB. For all 26 models, there is no way I can load them into my R environment for any kind of model comparison or averaging.Similar models run with mgcv::gamm() were only 5.7 MB, which is a much more manageable size for comparisons. (Note: unfortunately I have to stay within the gamm4 package based on model structure, otherwise I would use the mgcv model outputs).

Is there a way to decrease the size of the .rds file to a more reasonable size? Are there arguments within gamm4 or lme4 that could reduce the amount of extra information retained within the model?

Comment: The "butcher" package helps to understand and control the size of model objects.  https://butcher.tidymodels.org/  For instance you might run `butcher::weigh(A_MODEL)` to understand what's taking up storage space in the object. Often you can remove redundant training data and/or environment data.

Comment: @JonSpring this sounds  like what I need, however, I am getting the following error when I try to use any of the functions in that package `Error in obj_size_(dots, env, size_node(), size_vector()) : bad binding access`

Comment: @JonSpring thank you for the recommendation, however it seems that gamm4 is not a supported package or model type in butcher at this time.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example with some fake data? Perhaps the objects included data from the environment or training data -- does the size decrease if you remove unrelated objects from the environment or use smaller training data? I'm afraid we can only speculate without more context.